# Spreadsheet that calculates your RRSP contributions now, based on expected CPP, GIS, OAS, RRIF?

Tags: discussion

I don't want suspension, and just want check this. Would this question be on topic? It's not product recommendation when computer expert can create it free of cost.

---

Title – Spreadsheet that calculates your RRSP contributions now, based on expected CPP, GIS, OAS, RRIF?

---

I'm trying to determine the optimal RRSP contributions now to minimize taxes when I start my RRIF at 72. [This](https://old.reddit.com/r/PersonalFinanceCanada/comments/7xacnv/optimal_rrsp_contribution/du727ls/) doesn't consider, or let you input, your expected CPP, GIS, OAS, RRIF, and an assumed rate of return.

I don't know programming or computer science: can someone please create?

Comment: Matt - Off topic questions get closed. A member wouldn't be suspended for this, unless they ignored member advice on what's on topic and produced a flood of OT posts.

Comment: Just curious: If some planning tool for this purpose did exist online and were comprehensive and easy to use, would you pay for it? And how much? I've been pondering building tools like this for consumers. (Tools like this already exist for financial planners, but are expensive and complex, not consumer-oriented.) I am a Canadian, financially savvy, and a software developer. I think individuals are underserved by the financial industry, which is far more interested in getting your assets under management for fees rather than providing tools for DIY retirement and tax planning.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Yes - i would pay. I don't know how much. but people asking it are probably not richer than middle class. millionaires have advisors doing these spreadsheets for them!

Answer (score 2):

Asking someone to create a spreadsheet for you isn't on-topic - it's "Too broad" really. If you want to ask about specific details you'd need to know to make the sheet yourself, that might be ok. Likewise asking if one already exists is asking for an off-site resource.